# Why is 100% width broken on flex / block display?

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I am working on creating a responsive hamburger menu, within [PicoCSS](https://picocss.com/), as shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/brentarias/pen/gOQybod).  When on a small-ish device (`width < 48em`), I want the anchor tags of the fly-out menu to occupy the full-width of the enclosing <li> tag.  To accomplish this, I want to use the following CSS:

```
& a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

However, using `100%` causes almost the opposite to happen...where it consumes perhaps only 5% of the width, and even causes the text to wrap-to-fit.

So instead, I have to settle for the following change:

```
& a {
    display: block;
    /* don't know why a "100%" breaks this */
    width: 28em;
}
```

The above band-aid almost works.  If I fluidly adjust the width of my screen, I can see small under-runs or over-runs of the menu-link "hover" or "selection", as well as an unwanted margin "collapse".

I feel that it would be the best if only the `100%` setting would work.  Any idea of why that isn't working?  I want to be sure that the menu options can be "hovered" or show "selected" across the full-width of the menu.

Comment: 100% needs to go to the li not the a

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your answer worked!!!! Post your answer, and I will accept it.  Only, I don't understand *why* your answer worked.  All the examples I see online have the `width: 100%` placed on the anchor tag itself.

Answer (score -1):

the frame of reference is getting wrong for negative margin x (modern frameworks these days usually don't falsify this but old stuff like bootstrap will do them) add this to `@media`:

```css
& >ul.menu {
      .item {
        box-sizing: content-box;
      }
      & a {
        display: block;
        /* don't know why a "100%" breaks this */
        width: 100%;
      }
      & a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
}
```

Comment: I added the `box-sizing` as you suggested...and nothing happened, as if nothing was changed at all. :(

Comment: To be clear, after adding the `box-sizing`, the `width: 100%` caused the same problem as before.

Comment: remove your old css don't let it overwrite i tested before answer

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "remove old css".  Do you mean, remove PicoCSS?  Then it would not be answering my quetsion.  Do you mean, remove my media query?  Then it likewise would not be answering my question.   Perhaps you could post the *entire* CSS that you used, so that way I don't guess about what to delete or add.